# Building JPA Specification or Query for unidirectional OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

New to JPA specifications, I have the following entities
`Sale`, `SaleLineItem`, `StockItem`, `Product` and `ProductCategory`.

- `Sale` OneToMany with `SaleLineItem`
- `SaleLineItem` OneToOne with `StockItem`
- `StockItem` ManyToOne with `Product`
- `Product` ManyToMany with `ProductCategory`

Catch is `Product` class has no reference of `ProductCategory`
`ProductCategory` has collection of `Product`

[ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH9bF.png)

Class outlines are as below.

SALE

```
@Entity    
public class Sale {
 ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale")
   private Set<SaleLineItem> saleLineItems = new HashSet<>();
 ...

}
```

SALE LINE ITEM class is like

```
@Entity    
public class SaleLineItem {
 ...
   @OneToOne
   private StockItem stockItem;
 ...

}
```

STOCK ITEM class looks like

```
@Entity    
public class StockItem {
 ...
   @ManyToOne
   private Product product;
 ...

}
```

PRODUCT class skeleton

```
@Entity    
public class Product {
 ...
   private String productName;
 ...

}
```

PRODUCT CATEGORY is as follows

```
@Entity    
public class ProductCategory {
 ...

   @NotNull
   private String categoryName;

   @ManyToMany
   @NotNull
   private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
 ...

}
```

I wanted to query SaleLineItems based on productCategoryId. I made an attempt but am stuck with the following code.

```
    public List<SaleLineItem> findAllByProductCategory(LongFilter productCategoryFilter,
            Specification<SaleLineItem> specification) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<SaleLineItem> cq = cb.createQuery(SaleLineItem.class);
        Root<ProductCategory> ProductCategoryRoot = cq.from(ProductCategory.class);
        ListJoin<ProductCategory, Product> lj = ProductCategoryRoot.joinList(ProductCategory_.PRODUCTS);
        
        Root<SaleLineItem> sliRoot = cq.from(SaleLineItem.class);
        Join<StockItem, Product> kl = sliRoot.join(SaleLineItem_.stockItem).join(StockItem_.product);

        return null;
    }
```

Can someone kindly guide me?

Comment: Kindly describe your relationships between each entity or atttach the ERD.

Comment: Added ERD Diagram